# Aufstellungsort Vs Ort difference and usage

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, synonym

When we use **Aufstellungsort** instead of **Ort** to indicate a location? I found some references they use Aufstellungsort, while this word is not so common in many dictionaries and it even doesn't exist in [Google Ndiagram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%22Aufstellungsort%22%2C%22Ort%22&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%22%20Ort%20%22%3B%2Cc0)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Aufstellungsort* would be a special kind of *Ort*/location, namely a place where something is erected/placed/put (*aufgestellt*). For instance:

*Der Aufstellungsort des Temperaturfühlers sollte nicht direkter Sonneneinstrahlung ausgesetzt sein.* (The temperature sensor should not be placed in direct sunlight.)

The word *Aufstellungsort* is not commonly used outside of manuals/instructions.

Answer (score 6):

Most compound words in German aren't in the dictionary. You have to learn identifying the components. This one has

> Aufstellung-s-ort.

Track it from tail to head because the end is the most important part of a compound word. That's a rule.

*Ort* should be clear to you. A place.

*-s-* is the *Fugen-s* which is inserted as a pronounciation help. Without the -s-, there would be a glottal stop between Aufstellung- and -ort, which could be mistaken for a word border. That's why you need the -s-.

*Aufstellung* finally is a noun made from the verb *aufstellen*. Such nouns ending with -ung usually denote the type of action or result of an action. They are often used for compound words instead of infinitives made to nouns. *Aufstellen* in this case is *to set up*.

So this compund word decodes to *Place-action of setting something up*. A place where something is set up.